# using pascal case for vue component fails to register while built as library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

When use PascalCase for the component name the component is not registered by vue. Below is how it looks like

```
     <template>
      <div>
        <h6>This  is a sample reusable component</h6>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: "SampleComponent",
      data() {
        return {
        };
      }
    }
   </script>
```

This is how i am registering components.

```
    import SampleComponent  from './components/SampleComponent'

     const components:any = {SampleComponent}
     const ComponentLibrary = {
      install(Vue:any, options = {}) {
        for (const componentName in components) {
          const component = components[componentName];
          Vue.component(component.name, component);
        }
      }
     }


     if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.Vue) {
      window.Vue.use(ComponentLibrary)
     }

     export default ComponentLibrary;
```

While importing the library i get the below error

```
 Unknown custom element: <samplecomponent> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)
```

If i use just 'Sample' then it works.  Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Is the template that uses the component directly inside an HTML file? If it is then you'll need to use kebab-case within that template because the casing gets lost when it's parsed by the browser. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Name-Casing Note that the problem is specifically with in-DOM templates, not how you register the component.

Comment: You were its just an In-DOM direct reference issue.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the component name with kebab case in DOM has fixed the isssue. In any other vue project Pascal case  worked.

Comment: also, as an aside (not part of the question, but might want to be aware), when using vue components outside of vue compiler, you have to close your tags with a closing tag( ie. `<my-component />` will throw an error and `<my-component></my-component>` should be used